# Windows 11 Home - no option to "join this device to Azure AD"

Tags: windows, active-directory, entra-id

I have a work computer currently running Windows 11 Home. (I will update it to Pro/Enterprise, but I need to get this figured out first.) I need to "set up a work or school account" by connecting to my company's Azure Active Directory. All of the tutorials say that I should just click "join this device to Azure Active Directory", but my computer simply doesn't give me this option. I've been googling this for a few hours, but I haven't been able to figure out why this option is missing. What steps must I take in order to connect my computer to Azure Active Directory?

[image: the option is usually displayed here]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to upgrade edition first.
Home edition can't be joined to Azure AD

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/concept-azure-ad-join

Comment: Bruh I was trying to join Azure AD so that I could access the license key to upgrade lol. I'll have to talk to my admin. Thank you for clarifying!